# creating new project in java with maven

Tags: java, maven

I wanna create a java project with maven, when I type this command in cmd instead of creating a project it gives some error, I guess it is because of some internet problems but I don't know how to solve it. I don't use any proxy and I've tried this command even when my pc's firewall was turned off.
the command I write in cmd is:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.companyname.bank -DartifactId=consumerBanking -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

the rezult is:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
.
.
.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.167 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2012-05-18T21:09:38-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/254M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\a\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: What version of Maven are you using? I was able to run that command with no issue using a fresh download of Maven 3+

Comment: Why did you wait two years before posting this? Finished at: 2012-05-18T21:09:38-07:00

Comment: Try adding  -U at the end of the command. If that doesn't help, then it probably means that there is something preventing you from accessing the maven public repository.

Comment: I use maven 3.2.3 @RyanJ

Comment: there was the same problem, I don't know what prevents me from accessing the maven repository. any idea? @coderplus

Comment: You look like you have any kind of problem accessing internet. Are you behind a proxy? Do you have further messages there?

Comment: No I am not behind any proxy. @khmarbaise

Comment: Can you access https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom via the Web-Browser? From the command line? Consider posting the full  `mvn -X -e` log.

Comment: I can access that via web-browser but not with the cmd.@lexicore

Comment: If you can't access on cmd your are behind a proxy which is configured in your web browser...which needs to be configured correctly in Maven which mean in settings.xml.

Comment: I really don't understand!! in web browser "No Proxy" has a tick. how am I behind a proxy then?! @khmarbaise

Comment: You might be using a system proxy which is not always visiable in browser on which browser are workging on?

Comment: my system's clock was wrong and the problem was that,I use the mozila firefox anyway. @khmarbaise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're posting this in 2014, but the log says:

```
[INFO] Finished at: 2012-05-18T21:09:38-07:00
```

If your local clock is wrong, SSL won't work because the certificate will appear to be invalid, and your connection to https://repo.maven.apache.org/ will fail.

Fix your clock.